# Resumable index rebuild operation fails for filtered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Resumable index rebuild operation fails with an exception, it is on SQL Server 2019 CU23 and the DB is in simple recovery mode.

Exception:

```
Msg 10675, Level 16, State 2, Line 54
Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce a query plan. 
The RESUMABLE option is not supported for this index build. Remove the RESUMABLE option and rerun the statement.
```

Table definition with indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [value1] [decimal](5, 2) NOT NULL,
    [value2] [decimal](5, 2) NOT NULL,
    [date_created] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
    [date_deleted] [datetime2](3) NULL
) ON [DATA];
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [id] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [ID] ASC
) ON [DATA];
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [r_o_uniq] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [RID] ASC,
    [OID] ASC
)
WHERE ([date_deleted] IS NULL)
ON [DATA];
GO
```

Table size metrics:

```
InstanceName          : MSSQLSERVER
SqlInstance           : SqlInstance01
Database              : db01
Schema                : dbo
Name                  : MyTable
IndexSpaceUsed        : 1024
DataSpaceUsed         : 648
RowCount              : 12159
HasClusteredIndex     : True
IsFileTable           : False
IsMemoryOptimized     : False
IsPartitioned         : False
FullTextIndex         :
ChangeTrackingEnabled : False
```

Rebuild command:

```
ALTER INDEX [r_o_uniq]
ON [MyTable]
REBUILD
WITH (   ONLINE = ON
         (
             WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY
             (
                 MAX_DURATION = 2 MINUTES,
                 ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = SELF
             )
         ), FILLFACTOR = 80, DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE, RESUMABLE = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF
     );
```

- One easy solution that works is turning it into non-resumable, but
  checking if it is possible to figure out what is causing this error
  other than making it non-resumable and fix it?
- And, same table/index definition on other DB has no issues with
  resumable rebuild.

Comment: FWIW, index maintenance is wasteful and a waste. There's not much point in doing index rebuilds.

Comment: @J.D. If I get it right, you are suggesting this based on the resources rebuild process takes which out weighs the performance gains. How about the amount of page reads, IO and CPU requirements on a highly fragmented table vs defragmented table? With all the existing options available like ONLINE, RESUMABLE, MAXDOP, is it still not worthy to defrag them without impacting app workload to get a better performance with limited resources? Great if you could provide some insights of it.

Comment: "*is it still not worthy to defrag them without impacting app workload to get a better performance...*" - That's the fallacy though. Fragmentation doesn't affect performance, so there's no point in worrying about it. Index Maintenance isn't making your database faster. It triggers other operations that *can* help make your database faster, such as statistics updates and clearing the plan cache. You can run these things on your own, more granularly, and at a rate more conducive to your database, individually, without the overhead of index maintenance, which is resource contentious.

Comment: I get it from stats & plan perspective, how about physical data access? For example reading fragmented data scattered across 10 pages vs reading them from couple of pages when defragemented. Doesn't it benefit reducing disk IO, memory requered to hold 10 pages vs less pages?

Comment: Not on modern hardware no. It makes no measurable difference. Back when mechanical hard drives were standard, it might have mattered in some cases, but with modern disks, it really doesn't make a difference even with 99% fragmentation.

Comment: I'll certainly take into account your points regarding rebuilds. However, my current focus in this post is on a particular exception. I'm keen to see if anyone else has faced this condition and if there are any viable solutions to address it.

Comment: FWIW, I've spoken to a multitude of experts (including those who've worked on the product) on this topic and they agree with my original statement. Additionally, I personally don't particularly like to spend my time troubleshooting something that's not helpful anyway. But if you're still interested in it, best of luck!

Comment: Ack, thank you for your guidance on this.

Comment: Please put the table definition and any other relevant items needed to make a repro of the issue.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Added table definition to the question, but unfortunately the issue is not reproducable. It happens on one DB, but with same definition the rebuild operation was successful on different DB in different environment. Haven't tried `dropexisting = on`  to re-create, will try that and update.

Comment: Looks like to a certain extent this error is expected. Though the KB doesn't explain the circumstances that would trigger this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4551220-fix-assertion-error-occurs-when-you-run-resumable-index-build-statement-in-sql-server-2856a6b1-9c41-a040-fb3d-e01c8ded6fb3

Comment: @Martin Yeah, I wanted a repro to see if it was any different than previous found issues.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you, it is helpful. 
I have tried `dropexisting = on` and also dropped index and re-created to make it clean, but none of them able to solve the problem. For now I'm going to catch the exeception and handle it with `RESUMABLE = OFF`.
cc: @SeanGallardy